# Can't query GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql

I just want to query a GraphQL API I've been given. It is working if I send  the following query:

```
{
  stations {
    name
    code
  }
}
```

As response I get what I expect:

```
{
  "data": {
    "stations": [
      {
        "name": "Station1",
        "code": "ST1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Station2",
        "code": "ST2"
      },
    ]
}
```

The thing is I want to get just one result and I'd like to know how to use arguments because if I query this way:

```
{
    stations(code: "ST1") {
     name
     code
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unknown argument \"code\" on field \"stations\" of type \"RootQuery\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 11
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Take into account that I didn't create the API so I don't have access to data types

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is quite self explanatory. You cannot pass any filter param to the query since it looks is not supported. But with no more info than the error I am afraid we cannot help too much. Do you have access to the queries definition?

Comment: I don't have access to queries definition